# How to add multiple conditions in a formula in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

How can I rewrite the formula where multiple values in a choice field have to be met in order for the specific field to be shown:

```
=if([$field_15] != 'PERSON' && [$field_15] != 'NUF' && [$field_15] != 'DA' && [$field_15] != 'NUF' && [$field_15] != 'FORENING' && [$field_10] == 'SELVSKYLDNERKAUSJON' , 'true', 'false')
```

I get no syntax error in the following formula, but the logic doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: Is your `field_15` column of type single selection choice or multiple selection choice column? Also, can you explain the required conditions and expected results in words so we can help you with your formula?

Comment: Whether you use formula in the calculated column or JSON formatting?

Comment: @GaneshSanap - both field_10 and field_15 is is single selection choice. Field_15 have a total of 11 single select values. I want the current field to only be shown when 1) field_10 = "SELVSKYLDNERKAUSJON" and field_15 is not one of the values in the formula above.


Thank you for your response!

Comment: @EmilyDu-MSFT - I use the formula in the calculated column

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SharePoint conditional formulas**:

If you are using above formula for showing/hiding fields from SharePoint list form using **conditional formulas**, use this formula:

```
=if([$field_10] == 'SELVSKYLDNERKAUSJON' && ([$field_15] != 'PERSON' && [$field_15] != 'NUF' && [$field_15] != 'DA' && [$field_15] != 'FORENING'), 'true', 'false')
```

Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of your `field_10` and `field_15` columns in above formula. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Here's the Microsoft official documentation & steps for using conditional formulas in SharePoint: [Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

---

**SharePoint calculated column formulas**:

If you are using above formula in **Calculated column** formula settings, use this formula:

```
=IF(AND([field_10] = "SELVSKYLDNERKAUSJON",[field_15] <> "PERSON",[field_15] <> "NUF",[field_15] <> "DA",[field_15] <> "FORENING"), "True", "False")
```

Where `field_10` and `field_15` are the display names of your columns.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.